# Why does MySQL return "Access denied for user" error?

Tags: mysql, class, function

Here's an error message I am getting:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for
>   user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /var/www/classes/mysql.class.php on line 29 ERR_DB_CONNECT

I am using this database class:

```
class mysql
{

public $conn = "";
public $debug = 0;
public $queries = NULL;

public function mysql( $dbUser = "user", $dbPass = "pass", $dbName = "database", $dbHost = "localhost" )
{
    global $config;
    $this->user = $dbUser;
    $this->pass = $dbPass;
    $this->name = $dbName;
    $this->host = $dbHost;
    if ( $this->debug == 1 )
    {
        $this->queries = array( );
        $this->comments = array( );
    }
    $this->last_result = FALSE;
    $this->debug = $config['debug'];
    return TRUE;
}

public function connect( )
{
    if ( !( $this->conn = mysql_connect( $this->host, $this->user, $this->pass ) ) )
    {
        exit( "ERR_DB_CONNECT" );
    }
    $this->select_db( $this->name );
    return $this->conn;
}

public function select_db( $db )
{
    if ( !mysql_select_db( $db, $this->conn ) )
    {
        exit( "ERR_MYSQL_SELECT_DB" );
    }
    $this->query( "set names utf8" );
}

public function query( $query, $comment = "" )
{
    if ( !$this->conn )
    {
        $this->conn = $this->connect( );
    }
    $start = microtime( );
    if ( !( $result = mysql_query( $query, $this->conn ) ) )
    {
        exit( mysql_error( ) );
    }
    $end = microtime( );
    if ( $this->debug == 1 )
    {
        list( $usec1, $sec1 ) = explode( " ", $start );
        list( $usec2, $sec2 ) = explode( " ", $end );
        $diff = round( $sec2 - $sec1 + $usec2 - $usec1, 5 );
        $this->queries[] = $query;
        $this->comments[] = $comment;
        $this->queries['time'][] = $diff;
    }
    $this->last_result = $result;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: line 29  if ( !( $this->conn = mysql_connect( $this->host, $this->user, $this->pass ) ) )

Comment: I understand very little php help fix

Comment: in this case the base is present in the connection configuration file can not understand why this error shows

Comment: @user21: either your username or password is wrong, or your permissions for this user do not permit you to do what you are trying. Try resetting the password first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost*

This means that your account on your database does not have the correct permissions to perform any queries. Check your database; I imagine you're using XAMPP or something similar. To have a look at the database, type in `127.0.0.1` into your browser. If you have a password attached to your database, this might be the reason why you can't access.

---

**As a side note**

Do not use the PHP `my_sql` methods. They are deprecated, which means they are old, disused and vulnerable to security attacks, like [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [PDO Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).